# Can we place the 12 musical notes in the chromatic scale on a dodecahedron's faces such that the set of musical intervals at each vertex is the same?

Tags: geometry, music-theory

> Can we distribute the 12 musical notes in the chromatic scale on the faces of a dodecahedron such that the set of musical intervals at each vertex is the same?

(Assumes treating inverted invervals as equivalent, i.e. perfect 5th = perfect 4th, minor second = major 7th etc)

Notes can be represented by the numbers 0-11

Interval is the difference between the numbers.
Inverted interval means (12 - original interval).

Notes 0 and 2 have interval 2

Notes 1 and 11 have interval 10

Intervals 2 and 10 are equivalent inversions because 12 - 2 = 10
and 12 - 10 = 2

Context: I am interested in mapping musical notes onto polyhedra and it seemts to make sense to start with dodecahedra because they have 12 faces and there are 12 musical notes in western music. I have considered some sort of combinatorial search to solve for this, but maybe the concept is DOA for some mathematical reason.

Comment: I'm going to point in the direction of answer.  There are three faces around any vertex.  Say you fix the faces around a single vertex as, say, 0-4-7 (C-E-G).  Now the C (0) and G (7) faces share another neighbor, which must be labeled as E-flat (3).    Similarly the other common neighbor of C (0) and E (4) must be A (9), and the other common neighbor of E (4) and G (7) must be B (11).  If I'm not mistaken, once you have all three faces around a single vertex labeled, then you can expand that outward to get labels for all the faces...

Comment: ...but if I've done it right, starting with a major chord 0-4-7 you eventually get to a point where you can't proceed.  Basically you're trying to wrap the Tonnetz (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonnetz), which exists in the plane, around the dodecahedron.    It seems more natural to me to try to label the vertices of an icosahedron, so I googled "tonnetz icosahedron" and found an interesting-looking paper: https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/2103.10272/. Maybe there's some way to set the initial face that extends to labeling all twelve dodecahedral faces / icosahedral vertices?  I don't know.

Comment: @MichaelLugo: That sounds like a very plausible plan for a counterexample, I hope you write it up as an answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher if I can extend it to a full answer (either a labeling that does work or a proof there aren't any) I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose such a labelling exists. Clearly at most three different intervals appear on edges. Also every note meets five others, only two of which are at any given interval, so at least three different intervals must be used. So there are exactly three. Let's colour these red, green and blue.

Look at the five vertices around the face labelled with $0$. There is only one way to colour their edges (up to rotation, and permuting colours) with each vertex meeting all colours.

[image: The only way is GRGBRGBRGB.]

Now the faces to the top left and bottom right have the same (blue) difference from $0$, so they are $k$ and $12-k$ for some choice of $k$. But they also have the same (green) difference from the face to the top right, so that face must be labelled $6$. Now the same argument with right and left swapped shows the face to the top left must also be labelled $6$, a contradiction.

Therefore such a labelling is not possible.